# Django REST Framework and Vue.js throwing IntegrityError on post

Tags: django, api, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have an API created by the Django REST framework that is feeding data to my Vue.js frontend. That's going all well and good until I try to post to the API. The error I get is:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "ifflist_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (100, do more  stuff, f, null).
```

Here is the model I'm trying to post to:

```
class TodoItem(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # this is the text of the actual to-do
    ifflist = models.ForeignKey(IffList,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='item')
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here's serializers.py:

```
class TodoItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TodoItem
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Here's the API views.py:

```
class TodoListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = TodoItem.objects.all()  # this returns all the things, which is bad
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = TodoItemSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

class TodoRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = TodoItem.objects.all()  # this returns all the things, which is bad
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = TodoItemSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

The relevant urls.py:

```
path('api/', api_views.IffListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='ifflist_rest_api'),
path('api/todoitems/', api_views.TodoListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='todoitem_rest_api'),
path('api/user/', api_views.UserListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='user_rest_api'),
# api/:slug
path('api/<int:id>/', api_views.IffListRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.as_view(), name='ifflist_rest_api'),
path('api/todoitems/<int:id>/', api_views.TodoRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.as_view(), name='todoitem_rest_api'),
```

And finally, the Vue.js method where the magic is happening:

```
addTodo: function () {
  let new_todo_item = document.querySelector('#new_todo_item').value;
  this.newTodo = {'text': new_todo_item, 'ifflist_id': this.displayedIfflist.id};
  console.log(this.newTodo.text);
  console.log(this.newTodo.ifflist_id);
  let csrf_token = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
  this.$http.post('/api/todoitems/', this.newTodo, {headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token}})
      .then((response) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.getIfflist(this.displayedIfflist.id);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(err);
      })
    },
```

I'm on Django 2 and Vue 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turned out to be the depth property here:

```
class TodoItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = TodoItem
    fields = '__all__'
    depth = 1
```

Once I removed it, all was good. It seems like a weird DRF bug...

Answer (score 1):

```
this.newTodo = {'text': new_todo_item, 'ifflist_id': this.displayedIfflist.id};
```

change to

```
this.newTodo = {'text': new_todo_item, 'ifflist': this.displayedIfflist.id};
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to have the 'ifflist' id or the TodoItem won't be assigned to the right list, so it can't actually be null. The issue is that it shouldn't be null as is because the 'text' property is being passed just fine.

Comment: I see, it suould be `this.newTodo = {'text': new_todo_item, 'ifflist': this.displayedIfflist.id};`